# Realizar transformer a una coleccion hidratada con un modelo en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy teniendo un problema al realizar

```
public function index()
    {
        $usuarios=User::paginate(5)->toArray();
        $convert=User::hydrate($usuarios);  
        
         return $this->showAll($convert);
    }
```

Es necesario que realice la conversión ya que estoy utilizando un el paquete de laravel-fractal.

Este es mi codigo en mi trait para realizar al transformer de los datos

```
 protected function showAll(Collection $collection, $code=200)
    {
        if ($collection->isEmpty()) {         
            return $this->successResponse(['data' => $collection], $code);
        }
      $transformer = $collection->first()->transformer;    
      $collection = $this->transformData($collection,$transformer);
      return $this->successResponse($collection,$code);
    }
```

Bueno resulta que este no puede hacerme el transformer ya que lo realiza sobre datos nulos (cabe resaltar que si no utilizo el paginate() y solo hago una consulta all() al modelo, este transformer funciona de maravilla).

Haciendo un var_dump() en mi collection utilizando paginate() e hydrate() (adjunto solo una parte, mas abajo se obtienen otros array con los link de paginas) obtengo lo siguiente:

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#1287 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(12) {
    ["current_page"]=>
    object(App\User)#1295 (31) {
      ["transformer"]=>
      string(32) "App\Transformers\UserTransformer"
      ["table":protected]=>
      string(5) "users"
      ["dates":protected]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(10) "deleted_at"
        [1]=>
        string(10) "deleted_at"
      }
      ["fillable":protected]=>
      array(6) {
        [0]=>
        string(4) "name"
        [1]=>
        string(5) "email"
        [2]=>
        string(8) "password"
        [3]=>
        string(8) "verified"
        [4]=>
        string(18) "verification_token"
        [5]=>
        string(5) "admin"
      }
      ["hidden":protected]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(8) "password"
        [1]=>
        string(14) "remember_token"
        [2]=>
        string(18) "verification_token"
      }
      ["casts":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        ["email_verified_at"]=>
        string(8) "datetime"
      }
      ["connection":protected]=>
      string(5) "mysql"
      ["primaryKey":protected]=>
      string(2) "id"
      ["keyType":protected]=>
      string(3) "int"
      ["incrementing"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["with":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["withCount":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["perPage":protected]=>
      int(15)
      ["exists"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["attributes":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        int(1)
      }
      ["original":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        int(1)
      }
      ["changes":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["classCastCache":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["dateFormat":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["appends":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["observables":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["relations":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["touches":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["timestamps"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["visible":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["guarded":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "*"
      }
      ["rememberTokenName":protected]=>
      string(14) "remember_token"
      ["accessToken":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["forceDeleting":protected]=>
      bool(false)
    }
    ["data"]=>
    object(App\User)#1308 (31) {
      ["transformer"]=>
      string(32) "App\Transformers\UserTransformer"
      ["table":protected]=>
      string(5) "users"
      ["dates":protected]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(10) "deleted_at"
        [1]=>
        string(10) "deleted_at"
      }
      ["fillable":protected]=>
      array(6) {
        [0]=>
        string(4) "name"
        [1]=>
        string(5) "email"
        [2]=>
        string(8) "password"
        [3]=>
        string(8) "verified"
        [4]=>
        string(18) "verification_token"
        [5]=>
        string(5) "admin"
      }
      ["hidden":protected]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(8) "password"
        [1]=>
        string(14) "remember_token"
        [2]=>
        string(18) "verification_token"
      }
      ["casts":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        ["email_verified_at"]=>
        string(8) "datetime"
      }
      ["connection":protected]=>
      string(5) "mysql"
      ["primaryKey":protected]=>
      string(2) "id"
      ["keyType":protected]=>
      string(3) "int"
      ["incrementing"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["with":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["withCount":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["perPage":protected]=>
      int(15)
      ["exists"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["attributes":protected]=>
      array(5) {
        [0]=>
        array(9) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(1)
          ["name"]=>
          string(18) "Mr. Arlo Brown Iii"
          ["email"]=>
          string(21) "johnson57@example.org"
          ["email_verified_at"]=>
          string(27) "2020-08-03T20:43:43.000000Z"
          ["verified"]=>
          string(1) "2"
          ["admin"]=>
          string(5) "false"
          ["created_at"]=>
          string(27) "2020-08-03T20:43:43.000000Z"
          ["updated_at"]=>
          string(27) "2020-08-03T20:43:43.000000Z"
          ["deleted_at"]=>
          NULL
        }
        [1]=>
        array(9) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(2)
          ["name"]=>
          string(11) "Junius Moen"
          ["email"]=>
          string(18) "mwelch@example.com"
          ["email_verified_at"]=>
          string(27) "2020-08-03T20:43:43.000000Z"
          ["verified"]=>
          string(1) "2"
          ["admin"]=>
          string(4) "true"
          ["created_at"]=>
          string(27) "2020-08-03T20:43:43.000000Z"
          ["updated_at"]=>
          string(27) "2020-08-03T20:43:43.000000Z"
          ["deleted_at"]=>
          NULL
        }
```

Haciendo un var_dump() solo con all() y sin hydrate() obtengo lo siguiente (solo adjunto una parte):

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#1317 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    object(App\User)#1318 (31) {
      ["transformer"]=>
      string(32) "App\Transformers\UserTransformer"
      ["table":protected]=>
      string(5) "users"
      ["dates":protected]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(10) "deleted_at"
        [1]=>
        string(10) "deleted_at"
      }
      ["fillable":protected]=>
      array(6) {
        [0]=>
        string(4) "name"
        [1]=>
        string(5) "email"
        [2]=>
        string(8) "password"
        [3]=>
        string(8) "verified"
        [4]=>
        string(18) "verification_token"
        [5]=>
        string(5) "admin"
      }
      ["hidden":protected]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(8) "password"
        [1]=>
        string(14) "remember_token"
        [2]=>
        string(18) "verification_token"
      }
      ["casts":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        ["email_verified_at"]=>
        string(8) "datetime"
      }
      ["connection":protected]=>
      string(5) "mysql"
      ["primaryKey":protected]=>
      string(2) "id"
      ["keyType":protected]=>
      string(3) "int"
      ["incrementing"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["with":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["withCount":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["perPage":protected]=>
      int(15)
      ["exists"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["attributes":protected]=>
      array(12) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(1)
        ["name"]=>
        string(18) "mr. arlo brown iii"
        ["email"]=>
        string(21) "johnson57@example.org"
        ["email_verified_at"]=>
        string(19) "2020-08-03 20:43:43"
        ["password"]=>
        string(60) "$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi"
        ["remember_token"]=>
        string(10) "rUVsnHChjH"
        ["verified"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["verification_token"]=>
        string(40) "NcApGcxWCQORXP62tQeznniXjEBXRWeRMBK7aBWP"
        ["admin"]=>
        string(5) "false"
        ["created_at"]=>
        string(19) "2020-08-03 20:43:43"
        ["updated_at"]=>
        string(19) "2020-08-03 20:43:43"
        ["deleted_at"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["original":protected]=>
      array(12) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(1)
        ["name"]=>
        string(18) "mr. arlo brown iii"
        ["email"]=>
        string(21) "johnson57@example.org"
        ["email_verified_at"]=>
        string(19) "2020-08-03 20:43:43"
        ["password"]=>
        string(60) "$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi"
        ["remember_token"]=>
        string(10) "rUVsnHChjH"
        ["verified"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["verification_token"]=>
        string(40) "NcApGcxWCQORXP62tQeznniXjEBXRWeRMBK7aBWP"
        ["admin"]=>
        string(5) "false"
        ["created_at"]=>
        string(19) "2020-08-03 20:43:43"
        ["updated_at"]=>
        string(19) "2020-08-03 20:43:43"
        ["deleted_at"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["changes":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["classCastCache":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["dateFormat":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["appends":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["observables":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["relations":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["touches":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["timestamps"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["visible":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["guarded":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "*"
      }
      ["rememberTokenName":protected]=>
      string(14) "remember_token"
      ["accessToken":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["forceDeleting":protected]=>
      bool(false)
    }
    [1]=>
    object(App\User)#1319 (31) {
      ["transformer"]=>
      string(32) "App\Transformers\UserTransformer"
      ["table":protected]=>
      string(5) "users"
      ["dates":protected]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(10) "deleted_at"
        [1]=>
        string(10) "deleted_at"
      }
      ["fillable":protected]=>
      array(6) {
        [0]=>
        string(4) "name"
        [1]=>
        string(5) "email"
        [2]=>
        string(8) "password"
        [3]=>
        string(8) "verified"
        [4]=>
        string(18) "verification_token"
        [5]=>
        string(5) "admin"
      }
      ["hidden":protected]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(8) "password"
        [1]=>
        string(14) "remember_token"
        [2]=>
        string(18) "verification_token"
      }
      ["casts":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        ["email_verified_at"]=>
        string(8) "datetime"
      }
      ["connection":protected]=>
      string(5) "mysql"
      ["primaryKey":protected]=>
      string(2) "id"
      ["keyType":protected]=>
      string(3) "int"
      ["incrementing"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["with":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["withCount":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["perPage":protected]=>
      int(15)
      ["exists"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["attributes":protected]=>
      array(12) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(2)
        ["name"]=>
        string(11) "junius moen"
        ["email"]=>
        string(18) "mwelch@example.com"
        ["email_verified_at"]=>
        string(19) "2020-08-03 20:43:43"
        ["password"]=>
        string(60) "$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi"
        ["remember_token"]=>
        string(10) "UU3c9HnxfC"
        ["verified"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["verification_token"]=>
        string(40) "vJQhtdAsoiv4VOl3rAENeh9TfwxGlRNncoj9Mzw6"
        ["admin"]=>
        string(4) "true"
        ["created_at"]=>
        string(19) "2020-08-03 20:43:43"
        ["updated_at"]=>
        string(19) "2020-08-03 20:43:43"
        ["deleted_at"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["original":protected]=>
      array(12) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(2)
        ["name"]=>
        string(11) "junius moen"
        ["email"]=>
        string(18) "mwelch@example.com"
        ["email_verified_at"]=>
        string(19) "2020-08-03 20:43:43"
        ["password"]=>
        string(60) "$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi"
        ["remember_token"]=>
        string(10) "UU3c9HnxfC"
        ["verified"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["verification_token"]=>
        string(40) "vJQhtdAsoiv4VOl3rAENeh9TfwxGlRNncoj9Mzw6"
        ["admin"]=>
        string(4) "true"
        ["created_at"]=>
        string(19) "2020-08-03 20:43:43"
        ["updated_at"]=>
        string(19) "2020-08-03 20:43:43"
        ["deleted_at"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["changes":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["classCastCache":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
```

Al hacer un var_dump() en ambos casos sobre la coleccion->first()->tranformer, cuando lo aplico sobre el modelo paginado me arroja el objeto pero vacido, en cambio, cuando lo aplico sobre el modelo obteniendo todos los datos, me muestra efectivamente todos los objetos de tipo user, cabe resaltar que la coleccion paginada tiene un array data mientras que la que obtiene todos los datos no.

Ya intente con collection->get('data')->transformer pero no me deja hacer el transformer en este caso.
Que deberia hacer para poder acceder al data de la coleccion paginada para que esta si me la reconozca como tipo user?

Comment: ¿Y si usas el `paginate(5)` sin el `toArray()`?

Comment: No funciona ya que este devuelve un LengthAwarePaginator y el hydrate() solo convierte array a colecciones.

Comment: Resulta que si estoy obteniendo los datos, el problema es que mi transformer esta accediendo al primer objeto de mi coleccion (y este esta vacido) si puedes darte cuenta en el var_dump() mi segundo objeto de la coleccion tiene los datos de los usuarios, ha este quiero acceder.